# Working with two fragments, getting error: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-listfragment

**Edit (19/4)** I'm attaching a dropbox link, because the first error was fixed, but still the app crashes without a reason, it goes from the looper to the ZygotInit to kill the app, But I can't seem to find the reason nor the logcat gives any...
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2hrzqk9jnrlro0m/471jspyoCl

**EDIT:** The fragment_news_feed.xml: is the problematic one below...
The ListFragment is pretty long since it also contains asynctask, attching only the overrides:

> ```
> View feedView;
> ListView mRssFeed;
> ArrayAdapter<String> rssListAdapter;
> List<String> rssItemList;
>
> public NewsFeed() {
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
>     // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
>     SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
>     //mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);
>
>     if (savedInstanceState != null) {
>         //mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
>         //mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
>     }
>
>     rssItemList = new ArrayList<>();
>     rssItemList.add("T");
>     rssListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_news_feed, R.id.item, rssItemList);
>
>     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
>     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
>     // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
>     setHasOptionsMenu(true);
>     mRssFeed = getView().getListView();
> }
>
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     feedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, container, false);
>     //mRssFeed = getView().getListView();
>     /*String rss = "";
>     try {
>         rss = getRssFeed();
>         rssItemList.clear();
>         rssItemList.add(rss);
>         rssListAdapter.add(rss);
>         mRssFeed.setAdapter(rssListAdapter);
>     }
>     catch (Exception ex) {
>         Log.w("My News", "Exception Caught: " + ex.toString());
>     }*/
>     return feedView;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onStart() {
>     super.onStart();
>     new GetRssFeedTask().execute();
> }
> ```

***ORIGINAL:***
I'm writing a little application, with two fragments (one Fragment and one ListFragment) and two layouts (one of them is in one of the fragments).

The First fragment is:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"   
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#cccc"
    tools:context="com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

With onCreateView that works fine!!

The problematic fragment is the layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews.NewsFeed$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/feedlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the onCreateView for the second fragment is:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        feedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, container, false);
        mRssFeed = (ListView) feedView.findViewById(R.id.feedlist);
        // TODO here I need to reed the RSS and inflate the list with data
        String rss = "";
        try {
            rss = getRssFeed();
            rssItemList.clear();
            rssItemList.add(rss);
            rssListAdapter.add(rss);
            mRssFeed.setAdapter(rssListAdapter);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w("My News", "Exception Caught: " + ex.toString());
        }
        return feedView;
    }
```

I'm working with Android Studio, with gradle.
The build is smooth as butter,BUT... when I run the app,
when it gets to the secong onCreateView (shown above), The application cllapses with 
runTime Exeption Error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute
>   'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class

Although I got my layout inflated, and the list taken care of, I still get the exception.

What can be the problem?

Thanks i nadvance,
K.

Comment: This site is for users of Android, which means that questions about *writing* Android apps are off-topic here, so I've flagged your question to be moved to our sister site [so]. To start, though, you should read the documentation for `ListFragment` to understand why `android.R.id.list` is special, and why you might not want to use `ListFragment` at all in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Of course I first read the listfragment documentation before posting the question. Hope the move will be quick since I'm stuck on it for quite a while...

Comment: @AgentK post `fragment_news_feed.xml` and post the `ListFragment` full

Comment: Editted added the fragment.... Sorry for the dirty coding since it's still work in progress.....

Comment: Added a dropbox link: see update above https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2hrzqk9jnrlro0m/471jspyoCl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this

```
android:id="@+id/feedlist"
```

to

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

In onActivityCreated

```
mRssFeed = getView().getListView();
```

Or change

```
extends ListFragment
```

to

```
extends Fragment
```

Keep the rest the same.

Comment: OK, That did the trick but without the getListView thing, had to stick to getViewById.

Comment: @AgentK no need for that if you do it in onActivityCreated

Comment: The thing is that getListViews is not being recognized on Gradle even in onActivityCreate...